# How to cast result of SUBSTRING_INDEX to varchar?

Tags: mysql, sql

My `csv` column in `mytable` contains the following content as `TEXT` column.

```
john;doe;12;john@example.com
```

I want to create a view, but would prefer the resulting table being `varchar` columns. But instead, I'm getting `TEXT` with the following select:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv, ';', 2), ';', -1) AS test
FROM mytable;
```

Is it impossible to convert those fields to varchar or char?

Comment: ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad?r=SearchResults&s=1|177.7861)

Answer (score 1):

> But instead, I'm getting `TEXT`

Where you have taken this info from?

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (csv VARCHAR(250))
> SELECT 'john;doe;12;john@example.com' AS csv;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW my_view AS
> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv, ';', 2), ';', -1) AS test
> FROM mytable;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test
> SELECT * FROM my_view;
> ```

> ```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE test;
> ```
>
> ```
> Table | Create Table                                                                                                                     
> :---- | :------------------------------------------------------------------
> test  | CREATE TABLE `test` (
>       |   `test` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL
>       | ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d9bcb5f3d40f00bbeb48b3dd8952eb7)*

---

> I forgot to mention that the csv field is of type `TEXT`

If so explicit convertion needed.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (csv TEXT)
> SELECT 'john;doe;12;john@example.com' AS csv;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW my_view AS
> SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv, ';', 2), ';', -1), CHAR(255)) AS test
> FROM mytable;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test
> SELECT * FROM my_view;
> ```

> ```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE test;
> ```
>
> ```
> Table | Create Table                                                                                                                     
> :---- | :------------------------------------------------------------------
> test  | CREATE TABLE `test` (
>       |   `test` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
>       | ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d8706b3bb2db774010bb86df3b722e8)*

Comment: I forgot to mention that the `csv` field is of type `TEXT`

Comment: @membersound Updated.